# Itertools zip_longest with first item of each sub-list as padding values in stead of None by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

I have this list of lists :

```
cont_det = [['TASU 117000 0', "TGHU 759933 - 0", 'CSQU3054383', 'BMOU 126 780-0', "HALU 2014 13 3"], ['40HS'], ['Ha2ardous Materials', 'Arm5 Maehinery']]
```

Practically `cont_det` is a huge list with lots of sub-lists with irregular length of each sub-list. This is just a sample case for demonstration. I want to get the following output :

```
[['TASU 117000 0', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'], 
 ['TGHU 759933 - 0', '40HS', 'Arm5 Maehinery'], 
 ['CSQU3054383', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'], 
 ['BMOU 126 780-0', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'], 
 ['HALU 2014 13 3', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials']]
```

The logic behind this is `zip_longest` the list of lists but in case there is any sub-list whose length is less than the maximum of all lengths of the sub-lists (which is 5 here for first sub-list), then in stead of default `fillvalue=None` take the first item of that sub-list - as seen in case of second sub-list all reflected filled values are same and for the third one, the last three are filled by the first value.

I have got the result with this code :

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zilo
from more_itertools import padded as pad
max_ = len(max(cont_det, key=len))
for i, cont_row in enumerate(cont_det):
    if len(cont_det)!=max_:
        cont_det[i] = list(pad(cont_row, cont_row[0], max_))
cont_det = list(map(list, list(zilo(*cont_det))))
```

This gives me the expected result. In stead had I done `list(zilo(*cont_det, fillvalue=''))` I would have gotten this :

```
[('TASU 117000 0', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'), 
 ('TGHU 759933 - 0', '', 'Arm5 Maehinery'), 
 ('CSQU3054383', '', ''), 
 ('BMOU 126 780-0', '', ''), 
 ('HALU 2014 13 3', '', '')]
```

Is there any other process (like mapping any function or so) to the parameter `fillvalue` of the `zip_longest` function so that I don't have to iterate through the list to pad each sub-list up to the length of the longest sub-list before that and this thing can be done in a line with only `zip_longest`?

Comment: This was a neat puzzle. The only possible restriction with your solution is that it requires the length up front, making zip_longest and pad rather pointless. Aside from that, I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can peek into each of the iterators via `next` in order to extract the first item ("head"), then create a `sentinel` object that marks the end of the iterator and finally [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) everything back together in the following way: `head -> remainder_of_iterator -> sentinel -> it.repeat(head)`.

This uses [`it.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to replay the first item ad infinitum once the end of the iterator has been reached, so we need to introduce a way to stop that process once the last iterator hits its `sentinel` object. For this we can (ab)use the fact that [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) stops iterating if the mapped function raises (or leaks) a `StopIteration`, such as from [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) invoked on an already exhausted iterator. Alternatively we can use the 2-argument form of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to stop on a `sentinel` object (see below).

So we can map the chained iterators over a function that checks for each item whether it `is sentinel` and performs the following steps:

1. `if item is sentinel` then consume a dedicated iterator that yields one item fewer than the total number of iterators via `next` (hence leaking `StopIteration` for the last sentinel) and replace the `sentinel` with the corresponding `head`.
2. `else` just return the original item.

Finally we can just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the iterators together - it will stop on the last one hitting its `sentinel` object, i.e. performing a "zip-longest".

In summary, the following function performs the steps described above:

```
import itertools as it


def solution(*iterables):
    iterators = [iter(i) for i in iterables]  # make sure we're operating on iterators
    heads = [next(i) for i in iterators]  # requires each of the iterables to be non-empty
    sentinel = object()
    iterators = [it.chain((head,), iterator, (sentinel,), it.repeat(head))
                 for iterator, head in zip(iterators, heads)]
    # Create a dedicated iterator object that will be consumed each time a 'sentinel' object is found.
    # For the sentinel corresponding to the last iterator in 'iterators' this will leak a StopIteration.
    running = it.repeat(None, len(iterators) - 1)
    iterators = [map(lambda x, h: next(running) or h if x is sentinel else x,  # StopIteration causes the map to stop iterating
                     iterator, it.repeat(head))
                 for iterator, head in zip(iterators, heads)]
    return zip(*iterators)
```

If leaking `StopIteration` from the mapped function in order to terminate the `map` iterator feels too awkward then we can slightly modify the definition of `running` to yield an additional `sentinel` and use the 2-argument form of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) in order to stop on `sentinel`:

```
running = it.chain(it.repeat(None, len(iterators) - 1), (sentinel,))
iterators = [...]  # here the conversion to map objects remains unchanged
return zip(*[iter(i.__next__, sentinel) for i in iterators])
```

If the name resolution for `sentinel` and `running` from inside the mapped function is a concern, they can be included as arguments to that function:

```
iterators = [map(lambda x, h, s, r: next(r) or h if x is s else x,
                 iterator, it.repeat(head), it.repeat(sentinel), it.repeat(running))
             for iterator, head in zip(iterators, heads)]
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like some sort of "matrix rotation".

I've done it without any libs used to make it clear for everybody. That's pretty easy as for me.

```
from pprint import pprint

cont_det = [
    ['TASU 117000 0', "TGHU 759933 - 0", 'CSQU3054383', 'BMOU 126 780-0', "HALU 2014 13 3"],
    ['40HS'],
    ['Ha2ardous Materials', 'Arm5 Maehinery'],
]


def rotate_matrix(source):
    result = []

    # let's find the longest sub-list length
    length = max((len(row) for row in source))

    # for every column in sub-lists create a new row in the resulting list
    for column_id in range(0, length):
        result.append([])

        # let's fill the new created row using source row columns data.
        for row_id in range(0, len(source)):
            # let's use the first value from the sublist values if source row list has it for the column_id
            if len(source[row_id]) > column_id:
                result[column_id].append(source[row_id][column_id])
            else:
                try:
                    result[column_id].append(source[row_id][0])
                except IndexError:
                    result[column_id].append(None)

    return result


pprint(rotate_matrix(cont_det))
```

And, of course, the script output

```
> python test123.py
[['TASU 117000 0', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'],
 ['TGHU 759933 - 0', '40HS', 'Arm5 Maehinery'],
 ['CSQU3054383', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'],
 ['BMOU 126 780-0', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'],
 ['HALU 2014 13 3', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials']]
```

> Can't understand about `zip_longest` function. Is it a requirement for the solution or you need a solution "which just works" :) Because it doesn't look like `zip_longest` supports any sort of callbacks or etc where we can return required value "per cell" in the matrix.

Comment: `zip_longest` is not a mandatory requirement if and only if we could have done the whole thing way shorter than what I had already tried (it was already working). Nevertheless, your code works fine and gives the desired output.

Comment: yes, I like "easy to read later" solution rather then complex one-liners which are not readable without googling the python docs in a few days after writing :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in a general way for arbitrary iterators, you can use a sentinel value as the default, and replace it with the first value for that column. This has the advantage that it works without requiring you to expand anything up front or know the lengths.

```
def zip_longest_special(*iterables):
    def filter(items, defaults):
        return tuple(d if i is sentinel else i for i, d in zip(items, defaults))
    sentinel = object()
    iterables = zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel)
    first = next(iterables)
    yield filter(first, [None] * len(first))
    for item in iterables:
        yield filter(item, first)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. There is only [one](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) meaning for `fillvalue` argument. In any case there was another answer here, quite nice, but suddenly it was deleted. The code below is pretty close to that code but it works with `itertools` instead of list methods.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
def zilo(data):
    try:
        i1 = next(it := iter(data))
    except StopIteration:
        return zip()
    return zip(chain(i1, repeat(i1[0], len(max(data, key=len))-len(i1))),
               *(chain(i, repeat(i[0])) for i in it))
```

Comment: This will be specific to python 3.8 version with that walrus operator!

Comment: @Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev Of course. But what's the problem to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding another variation

```
def zipzag(fill, *cols):
   
   sizes = [len(col) for col in cols] # size of individual list in nested list
   
   longest = max(*sizes) 
   
   return [[xs[i] if i < sizes[j] else fill(xs) for j, xs in enumerate(cols)]for i in range(longest)] 

cont_det = [['TASU 117000 0', "TGHU 759933 - 0", 'CSQU3054383', 'BMOU 126 780-0', "HALU 2014 13 3"], ['40HS'], ['Ha2ardous Materials', 'Arm5 Maehinery']] 
                           

print(zipzag(lambda xs: xs[0], *cont_det))
```

produces,

```
[['TASU 117000 0', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'], ['TGHU 759933 - 0', '40HS', 'Arm5 Maehinery'], ['CSQU3054383', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'], ['BMOU 126 780-0', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials'], ['HALU 2014 13 3', '40HS', 'Ha2ardous Materials']]

[Program finished]
```

fill is a function that receives a list and should return something to make the lengths of the lists match up and make the zip work. The example i gave returns the first element of the column